# Java Prepared Statement Cannot Update Database

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement

I am using the prepared statement to store some variables into the database. The program runs without any errors but the database wont update.

```
 public void setData(Dealer sDealer)
 {
     String fName = sDealer.getFirstName();
     String lName = sDealer.getLastName();
     int age = sDealer.getAge();
     int xp = sDealer.getExperience();
     String mStatus = sDealer.getMartialStatus();
     String dAdd = sDealer.getAddress();
     String pNum = sDealer.getPhoneNumber();
     String email = sDealer.getEmailAddress();
     String crime = sDealer.getCriminalRecord();
     String type = sDealer.getCategory();
         String SQL ="INSERT INTO DEALERS  ("
                 +"firstName, " +"lastName ," +"dAge, "
                 +"dXp, " +"maritalStatus , " +"dAddress, "
                 +"phoneNumber, " +"dMail, " +"criminalRecord, " +"dType )"
                 +"VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

     try{
```

My suspicion is on the following prepared statement I used in this method but I am unable to figure out just what I am doing wrong.

```
         PreparedStatement pStat = dConnect.prepareStatement(SQL);

         pStat.setString(1, fName);
         pStat.setString(2, lName);
         pStat.setInt(3, age);
         pStat.setInt(4, xp);
         pStat.setString(5, mStatus);
         pStat.setString(6, dAdd);
         pStat.setString(7, pNum);
         pStat.setString(8, email);
         pStat.setString(9, crime);
         pStat.setString(10, type);

     }catch(Exception sx){
         System.out.println("Error is found :"+sx);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You didn't call [`executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the statement and commit these database changes by adding lines in try-catch block:

```
pStat.executeUpdate();
dConnect.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute the statement by adding one additional call:

```java
pStat.executeUpdate();
```